# Why doesn't .includes() work with .classList?

Tags: javascript

`element.classList` returns an array of classes, its my `understanding .includes()` is used with arrays, so I don't understand why this wont work, I know I can use .contains() with classList but I'm curious as to why .includes() doesn't work.

both are arrays, if I typed this for example it wont work

```
var li=document.createElement('li');
li.classList.add('main-nav');
li.classList.includes('main-nav');
```

but this will

```
var ary=['a','b','c'];
ary.includes('a');
```

Comment: You're looking for `contains`.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

[`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) is a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList) object, though it prints an array-like in console. But if you try on Firefox, it'd return `DOMTokenList["main-nav"]`

And, [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) is a **method** of [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) instead of [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList).

Which is why it's expected to encounter `li.classList.includes is not a function` in your case.

You can use [ES2015 spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) to cast it to be an array.

```
[...li.classList].includes('main-nav')
```

Or, you can also use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to cast it to be an array.

```
Array.from(li.classList).includes('main-nav')
```

Or no-hassle alternative, you can use [DOMTokenList.contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) method.

```
li.classList.contains('main-nav')
```

---

**Why is it declared as `includes` instead of `has` or `contains`? (thanks to @akinuri)**

Quoting from the [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/Array.prototype.includes/#faqs)

> The web has classes like [DOMStringList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMStringList) and [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList)
> which are array-like, and have methods named [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains) with the
> same semantics as our [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes). Unfortunately, meshing with those
> is not web-compatible.

Comment: space delimiter string? not a [DOM Token List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList)?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, it is.. I just happened to add more explanation about it after.. Still, thanks for pointing that out :)..

Comment: But don't they (include and contain) roughly mean the same thing? So what is the justification for using contains on DOMTokenList and includes on Array? It's a bit confusing. I sometimes forget which is which and find myself looking it up.

Comment: @akinuri Thanks for making me curious about that too. I've found a related reference and updated my answer.

Answer (score 27):

The reason `includes` doesn't work is due to `classList` not being an array, but an **array-like** object. In this case it is a [`DOM Token List`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList).

You can convert an array-like object to an array by using the following:

```
var liClasses = [].slice.apply(li.classList);
```

or

```
var liClasses = [...li.classList]; // es2015 syntax
```

---

Otherwise, `.includes()` should be `.contains()`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

```
li.classList.contains('main-nav')
```

> **contains( String )**
>
> Checks if specified class value exists in class attribute of the element.

Comment: @cashwrap that's actually impossible. The time this answer was edited is the _exact_ time the other answer was initially posted. --- **Theirs: "answered Jun 1 '16 at 10:59", mine "edited Jun 1 '16 at 10:59".**

Comment: You're right, there are a lot of similarities. The other answer is more comprehensive, but this answer was _by no means_ a copy. Besides the later edits were more than _two years after_ this answer. -- Anyway, your apology is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`element.classList` returns a [DOMTokenList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList). Here is an example from a firefox console.
[image: image of dev console in firefox]

And `.includes()` being a method defined in `Array.prototype` will work only for array objects.

[image: firefox console image displaying Array.prototype]

`DOMTokenList` has `.contains()` method to execute that feature.

[image: firefox console image displaying DOMTokenList.prototype]

[image]

Comment: this answer is valid